# ObservableCollection.Next() and observablecollection.previous() functions

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I have a observablecollection with 20 items(images) and button("Next").How I can get functions like observablecollection.next() and observablecollection.previous() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An observable collection has no concept of 'Current' or even of 'Selected' item. They are all equal.

You could keep a simple `int` index and Increment/Decrement it.

Or use the SelectedItem property of a bound ListBox or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest soultion would be to keep track of your current item using iterator - simple integer.

```
int couter = 0;
```

When you press the next button, check the counter if is not bigger that number of elements in the list and increment the counter:

```
if(counter < myObservableColection.Count)
    ++counter;
```

your previous function needs to check if counter is not negative number and decrement the counter.

You can try a more neat pattern with [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For just a next button, you could call [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132409%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on the ObservableCollection.  This will give you an IEnumerator<T> on which you can call Current and MoveNext.

If you need to implement a previous then you would use a solution more like lukas', with an index.